# Spring Security OAuth2 with Reddit - how to set "duration"

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently using Spring Security OAuth2 with Reddit - and trying to pass the `duration` parameter when redirecting the user to an authorization URL.

This URL is constructed via `getRedirectForAuthorization` - which is a private method in `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider` - so it's not immediately clear how the `duration` parameter should be added in.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a "duration"? Could you add it to a registered redirect URI as a query parameter? (I never heard of a provider requiring extra parameters on an authorization request.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add query parameters to the authorization request using a `RequestEnhancer`. You can inject one into the `AccessTokenProvider` and the `DefaultRequestEnhancer` includes a list of parameters to include (empty by default).

Comment: Hey Dave - thanks for the quick answer. I did notice the enhancer and I've been following the discussion that led to its creation. The problem is that it's the authorization URI that needs the extra parameter - here's the Reddit API showing an example: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#authorization

Comment: Isn't it the authorization URI that is created here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/grant/code/AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java#L130

Comment: It's created by this private method: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/grant/code/AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java#L315

Comment: Yes but it's created *from* the data that has passed through the _public_ `RequestEnhancer`. So to customize it you can use the enhancer. Am I missing something?

Comment: So, unless I'm missing something (which might very well be the case) - these are two different sets of parameters. The `getRedirectForAuthorization` method instantiates a new map and at no point passes that map to the enhancer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I think you are right. The enhancer can be used to tweak the form parameters for the token endpoint, but the authorization redirect is fixed. Open an issue in github.

Comment: No worries, I opened an issue to track this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/421. Thanks.